# Get column name by value of field in datarow

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, datarow, datacolumn

My question is actually more about optimizing something I already have working. 
 I'm having a hard time believing there isn't a better way to do this with a LINQ query or lambda expression, so I thought I'd try here.

Each of my datatable rows has an item number and 43 quantity columns, that each correspond with a specific day.  What I'm trying to do is take each row, and find the first quantity column that is greater than 0 and return that column name.  My solution does work, but I'd really like to make it more efficient:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) 
{
    for (int i = 3; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++) 
    {
        tempCol = dt.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString();
        rowValue = Convert.ToInt32(r(tempCol));
        if (rowValue > 0) 
        {
            tempCol = tempCol.Replace("Apat", "");
            break;
        }
    }

    var FirstAvailableDate = WorkDate.AddDays((dec)tempCol).ToShortDateString;
    //use data in someway
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions ahead of time!!

Comment: I don't think your sample compiles.  I spent three minutes staring at it trying to guess what the r method does, only to find it's a DataRow and you're using a string indexer which uses square brackets, not parentheses.

Comment: What is `(dec)` ?

Comment: The only thing in here that might possibly be worth the time to optimize is making sure your 43 columns are all typed as Int32 columns when you create the DataTable, then calling the GetInt or whatever method on DataRow instead of doing that Convert.ToInt32 thing.  Now, if you want to LINQify it, that's another matter, but that refactoring will slow it down, not make it faster.

Comment: are there significant amount of rows that all values are 0? (by the way, that is a good question for my opinion).

Comment: Another performance refactoring would give you higher locality of reference by scanning one column at a time.  Each column containing a primitive type is a strongly typed array of that type, so it's faster to scan down than across.

Comment: If you like linq : string[] results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray.Select((y,i) => new { index = i, value = (int)y}).Where(y => y.value > 0).FirstOrDefault()).Select(x => dt.Columns[x.index].ColumnName).ToArray();

Comment: Sorry about the non-compiling code.  The original is actually in VB and I quickly tried to convert it to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the current code, each row * each column

1. get name of column
2. store it in variable
3. in match case perform String.Replace

my suggestion:

```
var allCols = dt.Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(col => col.ColumnName.Replace("Apat", ""))
                .ToArray();

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    var firstCol =
    r.ItemArray.Select((cell, position) => Tuple.Create(Convert.ToInt32(cell), position))
               .FirstOrDefault(tuple => tuple.Item1 > 0);

    if(firstCol == null) continue;        

    var colName = allCols[firstCol.Item2];

    var FirstAvailableDate = WorkDate.AddDays((dec)colName).ToShortDateString;
    //use data in someway
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change following code

Tuple.Create(Convert.ToInt32(position), cell)

var colName = allCols[firstCol.Item1];

Working fine...!!!